# Naming txt file with hostname

Tags: shell

A simple question:

I have this:

```
hostname > test.txt
fdesetup status >> test.txt
```

How would I have it actually name the `.txt` file as the hostname of the computer?

example:

`computer1234` is hostname, so txt file would be created as `computer1234.txt`

Answer (score 8):

POSIXly:

```
fdesetup status > "$(uname -n).txt"
```

Some shells make the hostname readily available in a variable:

- `tcsh`/`zsh`: `fdesetup status > "$HOST.txt"`
- `bash`: `fdesetup status > "$HOSTNAME.txt"`

`tcsh` and `zsh` prompt expansions also have `%m` for the machine name up to the first `.` (for those systems where the host name still includes a domain part). In `zsh`, you can access it in a script with `${(%):-%m}`. Some systems have a `hostname`  command that takes the `-s` option (for *short*) to get you the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat hostname > "$(hostname -s).txt"
```